# Как отследить нажатие клавиши Ctrl+C на сайте?

Tags: html, javascript

Реально ли вообще отследить действие на сайте (копирование содержимого — <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> или правая копка + копировать) и как?

Comment: Делайте, делайте так. Это самый верный способ отвернуть пользователей от Вашего сайта.
Помните, что среднестатистический человек никогда не будет копировать всю старницу - ему это не нужно, а вот скопировать слово (например для перевода на свой язык) или ссылку, или цитату "для друга". Как думаете, сколько после этого пользователь продержится на сайте?

Answer (score 8):

Правую кнопку копировать не отследить, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> js отлавливается ну ура :)
Правую кнопку можно отключить, например так:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

А отловить <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> можно так:

```
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){ if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false; }
document.onkeydown=function(e) {
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 67 && isCtrl === true) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. А как узнать потом данные IP, браузер и т.д (вернее запиывать их в файл) человека (наподобии как в счетчиках Li). Помогите, отблагодарю.

Comment: Потом это когда? :)
Если в момент нажатия ctrl+c, то отправляйте ajax-запрос, а на стороне сервера получайте remote_addr и user_agent. А вообще, создавайте новую тему, а если вопрос закрыт, то отмечайте галочкой.

Comment: А зачем что-то посылать? В тот момент, когда пользователь начал грузить эту страницу, то он уже всё передал. Какой ещё может быть AJAX-запрос, если всё уже было передано?

Comment: Запрос все равно отсылать, я ведь так понимаю, что нужно записать кто и с какого ip пытался скопировать текст или нажать правой кнопкой мыши... Если следовать Вашему совету, то получается нужно записать данные куда-нибудь (например, в сессию), а послав запрос, выдрать их и сохранить уже куда нужно. Вообщем, насколько я понял, нужно именно в момент нажатия.

Answer (score 3):

Разочарую, но на 100% отследить нажатие клавиш нельзя.

- Во-первых, кроме Ctrl+c есть сочетание Ctrl+Insert, о котором много кто уже забыл, но это не значит, что оно не   работает.
- Во-вторых, есть программы, которые предоставляют больше буферов обмена с других кнопок.
- В-третьих, простое отключение js для сайта сделает невозможным отслеживание копирования.
- В-четвертых, при просмотре кода страницы можно легко выдернуть нужный текст.

Comment: Я думаю, что запрет системных функций и различные "защиты от копирования" полный бред и может только выбесить юзера, ИМХО.

Comment: + копирование содержимого через просмотр контента страницы или консоль firebug :)

Comment: Ктому же люди уже копипастом не занимают... есть парсеры и граберы для таких дел..

Answer (score 1):

В JS есть событие `oncopy`, которое можно отследить:

```js
document.addEventListener('copy', function(){
  document.getElementById('outs').innerHTML = 'You copy the text'
});
```

```html
<p>some text</p>
<div id="outs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того чтобы отлавливать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, можно запретить выделение текста в определенном div'е! Вот [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/18080/) есть хорошая статейка по этому поводу!

З.Ы. от выключения JS нет спасения)